# Syntax highlighting Java code in response to a Kotlin question

Tags: support, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71514438/2189127) to a question tagged `kotlin` and `javafx`. The code blocks in my answer were predominantly in Java.

Without any language tags on the code blocks, the syntax highlighting for the Java code looked as though it were attempting to highlight kotlin code. I tried to remedy this with various combinations of

```
<!-- language: lang-java --->

    // Java code here
```

or

````
```lang-java
// Java code here
```
````

or with

```
<!-- language-all: lang-java -->
```

at the top of the post.

These resulted in the code being formatted with no syntax highlighting, or with kotlin highlighting.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong in trying to override the language used for syntax highlighting?

Comment: The blocks are detected as Java. You can inspect them and they have the `language-java` class. But there isn't any syntax highlighting, on the other hand. Seems like a bug.

Comment: I tried removing (without saving)  the `<!-- language-all: lang-java -->` at the top of your post and [it helped a very tiny little bit](https://i.imgur.com/7Ntxf5N.png) there is *some* syntax highlighting in the preview but only in the first code block. The rest are still not styled.

Comment: To be clear @VLAZ removing the language-all markdown resulted in a "default" designation on that code block and highlight.js inferred the type as `lang-scss` to make that syntax highlighting. Which is... not optimal (or correct). (Other inferred types are `lang-coffeescript` and `lang-delphi` without the language-all)